# Flutter Centered SizedBox won't center

Tags: flutter

I want to center a SizedBox that I have created, so I wrapped it with a Center widget, like so:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      title: 'My app',
      home: SafeArea(
        child: MyScaffold(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyScaffold({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextInputWidget(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TextInputWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextInputWidget({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 200.0,
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: 'Enter a search term',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

But unfortunately, it does not work, as you can see on the picture below, the SizedBox is still on the left side on the window:

[image]

I have been looking for an answer, but did not find one yet.

Any solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`Center`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html) documentation:

> This widget will be as big as possible if its dimensions are constrained and `widthFactor` and `heightFactor` are null. If a dimension is unconstrained and the corresponding size factor is null then the widget will match its child's size in that dimension.

In a `Row`, children are unconstrained on the primary axis. To make a child widget such as the `Center` take up all the available space, wrap it in an `Expanded` widget.

([The `Row` API documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) has a detailed explanation of its layout mechanics. It's a very nice read.)

```dart
class TextInputWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextInputWidget({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 200.0,
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Enter a search term',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could set the `Row` alignment using `mainAxisAlignment` instead.

```dart
class TextInputWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextInputWidget({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: 200.0,
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: 'Enter a search term',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: indeed thanks, understanding the Row class is important in this case, I used the MainAxisAlignment.center though, it makes the code shorter

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `Center` widget you should use the `MainAxisAlignment` of the row:

```
class TextInputWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextInputWidget({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: 200.0,
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: 'Enter a search term',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I also needed an explanation

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to Center your SizedBox widget but the problem is, SizedBox won't able to know where it's position to centeralized because of its parent widget.

You can control that property with 2 options.

1st Solution using `mainAxisAlignment` property.

```
class TextInputWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextInputWidget({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 200.0,
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: 'Enter a search term',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

> or

2nd Solution using Flexible at here because you are limiting your SizedBox's width property, if you wan't to cover all the available space at Row's available zone's use Expanded instead.

```
Row(
  children: [
    Spacer(),
    Flexible(
      child: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 200.0,
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: 'Enter a search term',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Spacer(),
  ],
);
```

Comment: thanks but I didn't get the introduction sentence